# Populating Dropdown using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am working to populate a drop down from database. I am using jquery/jquery mobile. I am able to populate the dropdown. My issue is that when it gets populated, it does not show the 1st value, unless I select some other element and then select the 1st one again.

http://jsfiddle.net/hozefa/TtguK/

The fiddle above has the code I am currently using.

Comment: Maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/TtguK/11/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that you need to "refresh" the `<select>` widget using `.selectmenu('refresh')`:

```
var temp = ['5.00', '10.00', '15.00', '25.00', '50.00', '100.00'],
    output = [];

//notice I cached the `temp.length` value, the `for` loop will perform faster if this is done
for(var i = 0, len = temp.length; i < len; i++){

    //instead of appending each `<option>` element, it is a better practice to either concoct a string of all the HTML or create an array that will later be turned into a string (here we are pushing new indexes onto an `output` array)
    output.push('<option value="' + temp[i]+'">' + temp[i] + '</option>');
}

//now make a single `.append()` call with all the HTML in one big string
//and most importantly, call `.selectmenu("refresh")` after we update the HTML of the select menu so the jQuery Mobile framework will update the widget
$('#amountsList').append(output.join('')).selectmenu('refresh');
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TtguK/9/

Comment: @Hozefa You're welcome. If you take just one piece of info away from this, remember that each jQuery Mobile widget has something similar to this, they can all be programmatically created/refreshed.